# How can I use `rest/api/content` to download all the 800k pages of my Confluence wiki without timing out?

Tags: timeout, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I want to download all the 800k pages of my Confluence wiki.

I'd like to use:

```
curl -u wikiusername:wikipassword https://wiki.hostname.com/rest/api/content?start=1`
```

and simply increase `start` from `1` to `800000`.

However, the response time increases as `start` increases, and from ~`150,000` begins to timeout:

| `start` | response time (seconds) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.4 |
| 1,000 | 2.5 |
| 10,000 | 9 |
| 50,000 | 112 |
| 100,000 | 286 |
| 200,000 | timeout |

How can I use `rest/api/content` to download all the 800k pages of my Confluence wiki without timing out?

Comment: use the limit parameter as in https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/pagination-in-the-rest-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Option 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73048574/how-can-i-use-rest-api-content-to-download-all-the-800k-pages-of-my-confluence#comment129456869_73048574):

> Use the limit parameter as in [developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/…](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/pagination-in-the-rest-api/) - [Elazaron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1820776/elazaron)

Option 2: Download space by space, as this Python 2 script to export Confluence spaces and pages recursively via its API did: https://github.com/siemens/confluence-dumper ([mirror](https://archive.org/details/confluence-dumper)).

I confirm option 2 works.